# How exactly does memory handling (i.e, the function Release) work with Direct3D?

Tags: c++, memory, directx, direct3d

I came across a leak in a Direct3D application of mine, and I ended up correcting it, but I think the cause of the leak was due to my misunderstanding of how Direct3D handles its memory and interfaces.

I haven't been able to find a definitive article/tutorial on it (please provide one if you have one), but from what I've gathered, it works as such:

- Every time you call a `Get` method, the number of references for the object returned is incremented. So if I call `GetRenderTarget`, the surface being rendered to has its reference count incremented.
- Calling `Release` on the interface decrements its reference count. These first two points combined essentially mean: every time you get an interface, release it after you're done with it.
- When the reference count reaches 0, the instance is deleted.

I'm not entirely sure if this is correct, but it seems to work in practice. If someone could clarify/confirm how it works, that'd be great.

P.S, are there any safeguards implemented in releasing interfaces? Calling `Release` any number of times on the back buffer doesn't seem to do any damage (which is a good thing, but I'm not sure why it doesn't).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Direct3D is based on COM, which is a technology that's at least 15 years old.  Seems many people claim COM is dead and for that reason many overlook it, but reality is that there are many things in windows including Direct3D and MS's new Media Foundation that are all based on COM.

I strongly suggest you take a look at general COM programming.  There are plenty of books and resources, but many of them are rather old but that's ok because the root of the technology hasn't changed for a very long time.

Basically what you've observed is interface reference counting.  COM is based purely on accessing objects via interfaces, which all derive from the base interface, IUnknown.  IUnknown implements methods AddRef() and Release() and it is the responsibility of your application to call AddRef() whenever you store a local copy of a pointer and to call Release() whenever that local copy is no longer needed.

When you have methods with interface out parameters (i.e. IFoo** ppObj ), that means the callee is giving you back an interface and now that you have it, it is still your responsibility to call Release() whenever you are done with it.

Once you get the hang of it, I'd suggest you start using CComPtr smart class for storing local and member variables (still pass raw interface values between function calls, no need for smart pointer parameter types).  It will take care of all your reference counting.  Also don't make it a practice of calling release "any number" of times.  It might work today because the object is implemented as a singleton, or maybe something else is holding on to it, but that might change with next patch or next release.  Always follow the rules.  If you have an interface, when you don't need it call Release() exactly once.  If you made a copy of interface pointer, make sure to call AddRef() exactly once.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I would never call `Release` more than once in practice, I was just asking why it didn't tear the program apart when I was trying to figure this out and tried it.

Answer (score 4):

The application of addref/release semantics is much wider than COM technology. There is simple rule *one* `CreateObject()` (or `CreateTexture`, or `GetRenderTarget`, or `GetBackBuffer`, etc...) have to be confronted with *one* `Release()`, *one* `AddRef()` have to be confronted with *one* `Release()`.

In COM `IUnknown::Release()` returns number of references to object. It may delude you and you can think:
"Hm... I just call `Release()` until it return 0 and I will have no leaks. ???? PROFIT!!!!!111" <-- That is wrong! `AddRef` might be called by Direct3D itself or by 3rd_party library you pass this object to, or something else outside your app. *One* `Release` for *one* `AddRef`. You should call `Release` when you don't need object anymore, don't waste system resources.
You said:

> Calling Release any number of times on the back buffer doesn't seem to do any damage

That means nothing. May be The Universe like you so much or you just too lucky to not get exceptions from D3D.

Smart pointers (such as `CComPtr`) could make your life much easier if you will use them. In this case you don't need to call `Release` explicitly, it is called in `CComPtr` dtor if it is assigned to some object.

```
void get_surface(IDirect3DDevice9 *pDevice)
{
  IDirect3DSurface9 *surf0;
  IDirect3DSurface9 *surf1;
  CComPtr<IDirect3DSurface9> surf2;
  CComPtr<IDirect3DSurface9> surf3;
  CComPtr<IDirect3DSurface9> surf4;

  pDevice->GetRenderTarget( 0, surf0 ); // surface reference counter incremented, you should call Release() for this
  surf1 = surf0; // surface reference count is not incremented, you shouldn't call Release() for this

  pDevice->GetRenderTarget( 0, surf2 ); // surface reference counter incremented
  CComPtr<IDirect3DSurface9> surf3 = surf0; // surface reference counter incremented

  surf0->Release(); // release for pDevice->GetRenderTarget( 0, surf0 );
  surf2.Release();  // .Release() used not ->Release() - it is important
  surf4.Release();  // nothing happens because surf4 == 0
} // surf3.Release() is called in surf3 destructor
```

Also you may `#define D3D_DEBUG_INFO`before including direct 3d headers and switch to debug d3d runtime. It is helpful in finding leaks in d3d app.

May the `CComPtr` Force be with you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I didn't mean that I thought calling `Release` a hundred times was a good idea or that I'd ever think about doing it, I was just curious why it didn't break it. :)

Answer (score 2):

D3D objects are COM objects, and they use a basic reference counting system to manage the lifetime of the object. (See wikipedia for more info about the [Component Object Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_object_model#Reference_counting), or the MSDN article [Managing Object Lifetimes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687260.aspx))

The reference count is modified purely through the `AddRef`/`Release` methods, and certain other functions call those methods.

Creating the object as well as calling certain `Get` methods that return an object derived from the `IUnknown` class will call `AddRef` internally to increment the reference count, so you will need to call `Release` for each call when you are finished with the object.

If you pass the object to another function or class that stores a copy of the point (even temporarily) that class/function should call `AddRef` to ensure that the object is not freed while it is using it (and `Release` to signal it is done).

When the reference counter reaches 0 from a call to `Release` the object is signalled that it may be a good time to delete the held resources, but it may not happen immediately. There is also no protection for calling Release multiple times. The reference counter will not become negative, but it will not perform any other sanity checking (because it can't really) so you can cause application instability by trying to release references you don't hold.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. This is called reference counting and it ensures that objects are alive as long as they are being used, and no longer. You can use a variety of smart pointers to enforce this rule- both `shared_ptr` and (C++11) `unique_ptr` allow for custom deleters to call `Release()`. This makes it easy to control the lifetime of Direct3D objects just like you would for any other object in your application. You don't need to start including ATL libraries and CComPtr to use smart pointers with COM interfaces.